# install_github("bmschmidt/wordVectors")

Tags: r, windows, compiler-errors, word2vec

I am trying to install this package into my R enivornment. https://github.com/bmschmidt/wordVectors

I am getting compiler errors. It's the same errors identified on the github page. https://github.com/bmschmidt/wordVectors/issues/2

I'll post a shortened version here because there are about 130 lines that are almost identical.

```
> require(devtools)
> install_github("bmschmidt/wordVectors")
Downloading GitHub repo bmschmidt/wordVectors@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/bmschmidt/wordVectors/zipball/master
Installing wordVectors
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/usr/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpqw8mSh/devtools249437ed8a0/bmschmidt-wordVectors-6cfb717" --library="C:/Program  \
  Files/R/R-3.2.2/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'wordVectors' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"  -lm -pthread -O3 -march=native -Wall -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-result -w   -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c tmcn_distance.c -o tmcn_distance.o
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"  -lm -pthread -O3 -march=native -Wall -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-result -w   -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c tmcn_word2vec.c -o tmcn_word2vec.o
gcc -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o wordVectors.dll tmp.def tmcn_distance.o tmcn_word2vec.o -pthread -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library/wordVectors/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"  -lm -pthread -O3 -march=native -Wall -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-result -w   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c tmcn_distance.c -o tmcn_distance.o
gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"  -lm -pthread -O3 -march=native -Wall -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-result -w   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c tmcn_word2vec.c -o tmcn_word2vec.o
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1138: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rbx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1157: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss 4(%rbx),%xmm0,%xmm9'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1161: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rbx,%rdx,4),%xmm0,%xmm10'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1166: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rbx,%rdx,4),%xmm0,%xmm1'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1171: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rbx,%rdx,4),%xmm0,%xmm8'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1176: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rbx,%rdx,4),%xmm0,%xmm9'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1181: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rbx,%rdx,4),%xmm0,%xmm10'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1186: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rbx,%rdx,4),%xmm0,%xmm1'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:1196: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rbx,%rdx,4),%xmm0,%xmm1'
... Removed lines here as they all look like above and below ...
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:2677: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r8,4),%xmm0,%xmm8'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:2682: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r11,4),%xmm0,%xmm5'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:2685: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r8,4),%xmm0,%xmm4'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:2691: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r11,4),%xmm0,%xmm10'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccr7eSJc.s:2694: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%rax,%r8,4),%xmm0,%xmm9'
make: *** [tmcn_word2vec.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="wordVectors.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="tmcn_distance.o tmcn_word2vec.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'wordVectors'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library/wordVectors'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Here is my version of R running on Windows 7.

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Is this a compiler issue as the github dev suspected? Is there a specific compiler I should try? What do I need to do with R to tell it to use a different compiler?

I appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Your github issue and this don't discuss the *version* of Rtools installed. Are they the same? If you are using Rtools-3.3, you might want to re-download and reinstall it since it is not frozen. (I don't know that this is the problem, just a troubleshooting suggestion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution will be to use this implementation of wordVectors instead where I am not getting the issue.
https://github.com/cpeeples/wordVectors

I didn't realize there were so many copies and extensions of the this same code available before.